# Is there a way to install Google Chrome OS on an old laptop with no usb boot support?

Tags: installation, google-chrome

I would like to install Google Chrome OS on an old Presario 700 laptop that doesn't have USB boot support. Do you know of a way of installing Google Chrome OS from a CD like you would usually do for Linux installations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To boot the Chromium OS on a laptop that doesn't have USB support, use the LiveCD called Super Grub.

A full walkthrough of what to do is found at:
http://www.supergrubdisk.org/wiki/USB_Boot

The important thing to know is that it might not work for you.  Success hinges on if your BIOS offers Grub the USB drive as a boot drive.  As shown in the link, the USB might be set as the first or second boot drive.

Comment: er... that's not *official* Chrome OS - that's just a remastered Linux distro :\

Comment: You're right.  I never noticed before, as the sites that led me to it a while back never pointed out it wasn't Google's OS.  Let me fix my answer.